# jquery-ui - динамическое добавление selectmenu

Tags: jquery-ui

Суть проблемы: сделал я селектбокс на базе jquery-ui, первый селект работает отлично, но вот новые никак не хотят открывать список. Чуть ли не весь гугл перелопатил, но ответов для себя не нашел :((

[image: добавление selectmenu]

```js
  $(function() {
 
    $.widget( "custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
      _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>", { text: item.label } );
 
        if ( item.disabled ) {
          li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
        }
 
        $( "<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
        })
          .appendTo( li );
 
        return li.appendTo( ul );
      }
    });
 
    $( ".people" )
      .iconselectmenu()
      .iconselectmenu( "menuWidget")
        .addClass( "ui-menu-icons avatar" );
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение сам. Оказывается все довольно просто(и это я полдня голову ломал), все решается в 4-ре строки)

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {

    $(".init-ui").iconselectmenu("destroy"); // Уничтожаем плагин
    $(".sub-block1").clone(true).appendTo(".block"); // Клонируем и перемещаем элемент в конец родителя
    $(".init-ui").iconselectmenu().iconselectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar"); // Восстанавливаем плагин
});
```